# Function not defined error while using asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i am trying to call a web service through asp.net ajax by the following code

```
namespace MCTS70515AJAX
{
public static class HR
{
    public static int GetEmployeeCount(string department)
    {
        int count = 0;
        switch (department)
        {
            case "Sales":
                count = 10;
                break;
            case "Engineering":
                count = 28;
                break;
            case "Marketing":
                count = 44;
                break;
            case "HR":
                count = 7;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

this is the aspx page i am rendering

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AJAX2.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="MCTS70515AJAX.AJAX2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="HRSer.asmx" />
            </Services>
            <Scripts>

            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>


        <div>
            <select id="Departments" size="5">
                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                <option value="HR">Human Resources</option>
                <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
                <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>

            </select>

        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <span id="employeeResults"></span>
            <span id="loading" style="display: none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading ... 

            </span>

        </div>

    </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    var departments = null;
    Sys.Application.add_load(page_load);
    Sys.Application.add_unload(page_unload);
    function page_load(sender, e) {
        departments = $get("Departments");
        $addHandler(departments, "change", departments_onchange);
    }
    function page_unload(sender, e) {
        $removeHandler(departments, "change", departments_onchange);
    }
    function departments_onchange(sender, e) {
        $get("employeeResults").innerHTML = ""; $get("loading").style.display = "block";
        var selectedValue = departments.value;
        HRService.Getcount(selectedValue, onSuccess);
    }
    function onSuccess(result) {
        $get("loading").style.display = "none";
        $get("employeeResults").innerHTML = "Employee count: " + result;
    }


                </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the web service i am calling

```
namespace MCTS70515AJAX
{

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HRService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public int Getcount(string department)
    {
        return HR.GetEmployeeCount(department);
    }
}
```

}
the page renders fine but whenever i change the list item value, it shows JavaScript runtime error: 'HRService' is undefined. why is this.

Sorry for such a long post ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can can try `PageMethods`, just add the `using` and the `[WebMethod]`

```
using System.Web.Services;

public static class HR
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static int GetEmployeeCount(string department)
        {
            int count = 0;
            ...
            return count;
        }
    }
```

In your aspx modify your scriptManager like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

then you can call the method in the JS this way

```
function myJS_method() {
    var departments = $get("Departments"); // your string value
    PageMethods.GetEmployeeCount(departments , onSucess, onError);
    function onSucess(result) {
        // your code when it is OK
        // result is the return value of your C# method
    }
    function onError(result) { alert('Error' + result); }
}
```

Comment: this does not work and now it says  JavaScript runtime error: 'PageMethods' is undefined

Comment: Are you sure you add the EnablePageMethods attribute in the ScriptManager, add the [WebMethod] to the method and add the using line? these last two things in your HR class not in your HRService

Comment: this surely works, thanks a lot but can you tell how to make use of it when using a web service (.asmx)

Comment: @Vishesh use a WCF service, not asmx. If you have an existing asmx service you can migrate it using the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412168%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)