# how to call jquery ajax to c# page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, c#-2.0

How to call jquery ajax to c# page there is no response from visual studio tried through break point

first tried with Big one no response from C# side(ProfitCentersNameInsert) function then tried another simple type (apply) function but no response from both methods 
just commented the below lines on Ajax

```
//    url: "ProfitCentersScreen.aspx/ProfitCentersNameInsert",
//  data: "{'ProfitCenterName':'" + ProfitCenterName + "'}",
```

### JS Code

```
$(function() {
    profit.onRefresh()
    $( "#btnAdd" ).click(profit.onClickSave);
});

var profit = {
    onRefresh: function(){},

    onClickSave: function(){
        var ProfitCenterName =$('#txtProfitCenter').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //    url: "ProfitCentersScreen.aspx/ProfitCentersNameInsert",
            url: "ProfitCentersScreen.aspx/apply",
          //  data: "{'ProfitCenterName':'" + ProfitCenterName + "'}",
            data:'{}',

            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert( response );
                alert(ProfitCenterName);
                $('#txtProfitCenter').val('');
                alert("Record saved successfully..!!");
            },
            error: function () { 
                alert("Error");
            }
        }); 
    }   
};
```

### C# Code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string ProfitCentersNameInsert(string ProfitCenterName)
    {

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.133;User Id=hll; " + "Password=hll;Database=checking_DB;"); //+ "Pooling=true;MaxPoolSize=100;Timeout=20;"
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into tbl_Profit_Centers(Profit_Center_Id,Profit_center_Name) Values(default,@ProfitCenterName)", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfitCenterName", ProfitCenterName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "failure";
        }

    }


    [WebMethod]
    public static string apply()//method must be "pulic static" if it is in aspx page
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
```

Comment: if you are using firefox try right clicking your web page, click inspect element and then check the network tab then do whatever it is that is supposed to fire your post and see if it shows up in the network tab

Comment: Have you declare the jquery library in the <head> section?

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082988/function-not-defined-error-while-using-asp-net-ajax/30083658#30083658

Answer (score 0):

> try This

```
 url: "ProfitCentersScreen.aspx",
 data: {ProfitCenterName: ProfitCenterName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response.d` in your success

```
 success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                alert("Record saved successfully..!!");
            },
```

Here's pseudo code a simple jQuery Ajax call

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#bntAJax").on('click', function (e) {
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // your  webmethod   
                url: "AjaxFunction/myFunction.asmx/apply",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });
    
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
    
            function OnErrorCall() {
           
            }
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

---

**WebMethod :**

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string apply()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below points, it should work :

1) if your page is at root level of project then the url should be like below :

```
url: "/ProfitCentersScreen.aspx/apply"
```

OR

```
url: "../ProfitCentersScreen.aspx/apply"
```

2) stringify your parameter

```
data: JSON.stringify({})
```

3) Finally add this parameter

```
dataType: "json",
```