# Calling Code-Behind function from AJAX directly without page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, dotnetnuke

I am trying to call a code behind function directly. At the moment I am able to call the function from the PageLoad event of my ajax.aspx.vb and I pass the response through my variable which is on the ajax.aspx `<%= m_result %>`. This works fine. However, I do not want to go through the PageLoad event, but to target the function directly without having to put data into the `<%= m_result %>`. Is it possible?

I am using DotNetNuke where all the functionality are comes from ascx controls.
So, in my `ascx` control I have the ajax as:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function JSFunction() {
        var xx = 1;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/top3/DesktopModules/top3all/ajax.aspx/GetTestData",
                data: { 'sPageIndex': xx},
            }).done(function (response) {
             OnSuccessTest(response);
            });
    }
    function OnSuccessTest(response) {
        document.getElementById("<%= lblTest.ClientID%>").innerHTML = response;
}
</script>
```

In my ajax.aspx.vb:

```
 Protected m_result As String = ""

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim sModuleIDReferrer As String
        If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer Is Nothing Then
            strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString

            Dim sPageIndex As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(Request("sPageIndex"), sPageIndex) Then

                GetTestData(sPageIndex)
            End If
          End If
    End Sub

 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetTestData(ByVal name As Integer) As String
        m_result = "some test"
        Return m_result
    End Function
```

In my ajax.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ajax.aspx.vb" Inherits="Christoc.Modules.top3all.ajax" %>
<%= m_result %>
```

Comment: I think you need to declare the method you want to call as a WebMethod, and I think you need to declare it static...

Comment: Like @DavidW said you should probably create a WebMethod. See this [example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx). In VB static methods are called Shared

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is what you need --

In your aspx page, add a ScriptManager control, and set its EnablePageMethods property to True

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="MySM" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />
```

Modify your method declaration in the codebehind as follows:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function GetTestData(ByVal name As Integer) As String
        m_result = "some test"
        Return m_result
 End Function
```

Comment: I have tried that already but it still goes through the PageLoad and since I'm not populating the m_result in the PageLoad it returns nothing.

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager control on your form? If not, add one, and set EnablePageMethods=True (Just edited the ansewr to include this for completeness).

Comment: Oooh one other item - in your call to the function, you call the parameter "sPageIndex" but the formal parameter name is 'name'. Think those have to match the method signature.

Comment: I cannot add a ScriptManager because it's already have references to a built-in script manager. On the built-in script manager I wasn't able to set the EnablePageMethods=true

Comment: Built-in script manager? Could you expand on that a bit? Is it in a master page or something such as that? I take it it's something other than the standard ASP ScriptManager? If so, that might be a factor in your issue. Maybe if you posted some or all of your aspx markup it might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will do some research and let you know

Answer (score 0):

After adding `<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>` as @David says, you could try changing your JS to use PageMethods, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082988/function-not-defined-error-while-using-asp-net-ajax/30083658#30083658), there you can find all you need.

Hope this help