# Web service call with ajax in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use web service using jquery ajax. The webservice method is called and the parameter are passed as well, I wonder why the ajax would not execute success function

Here's my ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btn_add() {
        var a = $("#tb_a").val();
        var b = $("#tb_b").val();
        var c = $("#tb_c").val();
        var para = "a=" + a + "&b=" + b + "&c=" + c;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mywebservice.asmx/add",
            data: para,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (res) {
                alert("success");
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**

Here is my webservice code

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class mywebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
        public int add( int a, int b, int c)
        {
            return a + b + c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. I would imagine from looking at your code it's a 400 or 500 error. If it's the latter, seeing your server side code would help too

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it says that your call could be like like this:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mywebservice.asmx/add",
        data: { a : $("#tb_a").val(), 
                b : $("#tb_b").val(),
                c : $("#tb_c").val() },
        success: function (res) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

if in your server you have this:

```
public string myFunction(string a, string b, string c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

now, if that doesn't work, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082988/function-not-defined-error-while-using-asp-net-ajax/30083658#30083658), it's a different way to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting 404 error, check it your console, coz your `add` method signature is not matched what you send in your ajax call.
You can try like this

```
var aData=[];
    aData[0] = $("#tb_a").val();
    aData[1] = $("#tb_b").val();
    aData[2] = $("#tb_c").val();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData:aData});
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mywebservice.asmx/add", 
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });
        
    function OnSuccess(response){
     console.log(response.d);
    }
    
    function OnErrorCall(response){
     console.log(response.d);
    }
```

---

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
  public int add(list<string> aData)
 {
     int cal=Convert.ToInt32(aData[0])+Convert.ToInt32(aData[1])+Convert.ToInt32(aData[2]);
    return cal;
 }
```

Comment: It still won't work. If I apply breakpoint in ajax call in js, then it reaches the success function and shows result. If I don't apply breakpoint and just run the program, there is nothing. Even the console of firebug displays error for a second and disappear. I am so confused.