# fetching and populating values in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, autopostback, modalpopup

This is what I'm trying to achieve here. The user clicks on a button and the bootstrap modal popup appears. The user enters the event id value in the text box of the modal popup and I want information regarding the event to be displayed on the other fields in the modal popup.

I wrote a function under **txtEventId_TextChanged** event and I was able to get the value entered in the event id textbox. I was able to pass that value to the database and retrieve it's corresponding values from database as well.

My problem now is that I'm not able to display those data in the modal popup.

Here is the HTML Code :

```
          <!-- Maintainenance Modal -->


        <div class="modal fade" id="maintenanceModal" role="dialog" tabindex = -1 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

               <!-- Maintaineance Modal content-->

                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                               <h4 class="modal-title">Maintain Event</h4>
                        </div>

                          <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <div class ="form-group">
                                        <label for="eventID" id="lblEventId">EventID</label> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEventId" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dialogtextbox" AutoPostBack="false" OnTextChanged="txtEventId_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="EventsIcons"> 
                         <div class ="form-group">
                            <label for="MaintainDropDown" id="MaintainEventLabel">Select The Event Type </label>
                            <select id="MaintainDropDown" runat="server" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle eventdropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                <option value="WorkAnniversary">WORKANNIVERSARY</option>
                                <option value="Birthday">BIRTHDAY</option>
                                <option value="Community">COMMUNITY</option>
                                <option value="FoodSafety">FOOD SAFETY</option>
                                <option value="Health&Safety">HEALTH & SAFETY</option>
                                <option value="Holiday">HOLIDAY</option>
                                <option value="Maintenance">MAINTENANCE</option>
                                <option value="QualityAudit">QUALITY AUDIT</option>
                                <option value="SocialEvent">SOCIAL EVENT</option>
                                <option value="Stat-Holiday">STAT-HOLIDAY</option>
                                <option value="Sustainability">SUSTAINABILITY</option>
                                <option value="TownHall">TOWN HALL</option>
                                <option value="Visitor">VISITOR</option>
                                <option value="Wellness">WELLNESS</option>
                            </select> 
                        </div>


                 </div> 

                    <div class="Description">
                        <label for="description" id="MaintainDescription">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="maintainTxtDescription" name="eventdescription" runat="server"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id="Label3">Start Time</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id="maintainStartDate">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="maintainTxtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dialogtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="startTime">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="maintainTxtStartTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dialogtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="Label4">End Time</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="endDate">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="maintainTxtEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dialogtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">    
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>   
                          <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group date" id="endTime">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="maintainTxtEndTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control dialogtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="maintainChkBoxAllDayEvents" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" Text="All Day Event" OnClick="document.getElementById('maintainTxtStartTime').disabled = this.checked;document.getElementById('maintainTxtEndTime').disabled = this.checked;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnMaintainSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" 
                                    CssClass="btn btn-group-justified btn-success" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is my code behind code.

```
    protected void txtEventId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BusinessLogicLayer BL = new BusinessLogicLayer();

        EventId = Convert.ToInt32(txtEventId.Text);

        try
        {
          DataTable dt =  BL.BLGetEventDetails(EventId);

          foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
          {
              StartDate = row["StartDate"].ToString();
              EndDate = row["EndDate"].ToString();
              StartTime = row["StartTime"].ToString();
              EndTime = row["EndTime"].ToString();
              EventDescription = row["EventDescription"].ToString();
              EventType = row["EventType"].ToString();

              if (StartDate.Equals(""))
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("EventId Does Not Exists");
                  maintainTxtStartDate.Text = "";
                  maintainTxtStartTime.Text = "";
                  maintainTxtEndDate.Text = "";
                  maintainTxtEndTime.Text = "";
                  MaintainDropDown.Disabled = true;
              }
              else
              {
                  maintainTxtStartDate.Text = StartDate;
                  maintainTxtStartTime.Text = StartTime;
                  maintainTxtEndDate.Text = EndDate;
                  maintainTxtEndTime.Text = EndTime;
                  MaintainDropDown.Value = EventType;
                  maintainTxtDescription.InnerText = EventDescription;
              }

          }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "txtEventId_TextChanged", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

If I specify **AutoPostBack="true"** for txtEventId then the popup disappears from the screen after I input the value and hit enter. If I set the **AutoPostBack = "false"** then it is not populating the values as the control is not going to **txtEventId_TextChanged** function. I do not want to set AutoPostBack="true" because during postback the whole page will reload and the modal popup will disappear. I tried setting scriptmanager and updatepanel for it but since I have already an another existing scriptmanager and updatepanel added in the Default.aspx page, I'm not able to add a new one to it.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to rectify this. Your guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx)

   Use the RegisterStartupScript at the end of your method to send JS code to the client, you will send the call to your modal like this

   ```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "callModal", 
   "$('#maintenanceModal').modal();", true);
   ```

   This is the easiest way to accomplish what you want
2. [PageMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.110).aspx)

   You can use the PageMethods to return a JSON with the values you want to display, this way you don't need to do a Postback, and you will get the info you want. See the [requirements and how to use PageMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083658/4773983)